# How can you build mob traps in Minecraft Pocket Edition?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

In Minecraft pocket edition, can you build a trap that will kill hostile and passive mobs?

I am trying to build a trap in Minecraft PE but no mobs are falling into it. Right now it is a water trap using a natural waterfall that drowns them. It works on me (If I do not mine) and animals that get pushed in, but no animals walk in on their own. I have animals swarming all over the place.

Are there any traps that would work that won't take so long to build? If so, can you please show me how to build one.

I do not care if I kill them or not, I just want the items. I also do not care if it works on players or not.I know that you do not have lava, buckets, spawners, redstone or most other things that would make it easier. I have about 1000 dirt or so, but I have not found any cactus in my world either.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Simple Mob Grinder

The simplest mob grinder you can do is to use gravity to kill off the mobs.

Build a really tall hollow tower out of cobblestones with no windows. Make sure the hollow shaft is 2x2 wide so there is enough space for spiders to fall down as well as any other mobs. Make sure this shaft is built over something solid - stone, not sand, dirt or gravel. The reason this is all dark is so that the mobs will still spawn during the day as well as at night.

At the top of this tower create a large room, again with no windows. Something around 15x15 will do. Make it about 5 blocks high and keep a hole in the floor over the shaft so that you have a big dark room with a shaft in the middle. In theory the mobs will spawn in this big room, wander around and fall down the shaft, splatting on the ground and leaving a load of goodies for you to sweep up. Don't forget to add a door at the bottom of the shaft so you can get in there and grab it all.

Really that should be all you need. You can expand this idea however you fancy; underground grinders, multi-room grinders... however adventurous you want to go. Bear in mind though that Mobs will only spawn when you are near to them, so you should build a house near to your grinder, or at least hang around near it when you want to get stuff.

Comment: This will work even better in the next update where they are adding buckets.

Comment: @jacen.garriss be aware though, buckets are still relatively new and water placed by players does not work as well.

Answer (score 5):

I created a mob trap that uses water to channel the mobs to a center location and have a fall trap located on the bedrock level that collects the loot. I had to build a rather extensive underground irrigation system and a water tank to get the water to the places I needed it in the trap. Works like a charm. I built mine 3 levels high with a 27 block drop in the center. It generally grinds 30-50 mobs a minute.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think mobs can drown. I am pretty sure there are no other ways to kill mobs without using a cactus.

Comment: Mobs can drown in MC on the PC, not sure about pocket edition.

Answer (score 1):

One like this takes 9 minutes to build you may need a lot of glass but it's worth it!
[image]

[image]

Was built in version 0.8.1

Comment: Lava destroys items,so mobs won't drop loot. Try adding a small space nearby where mobs have a chance to drop items more safely. Well,actually,they drop loot but it can be destroyed by lava immedeatly.